# Creating a sqlCommand to Update a table on one mssql server from another mssql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the code i have right now that is working

```
'Declaring Connection String
        Dim sqlConnectionString As String
        sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("baminterchangerConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)

'Declaring SQL Queries
        Dim insertSQL As String = "insert into [dbo].[imports](OEMPartNumber) values (@OEMPartNumber)"
        Dim update As String = "UPDATE a SET a.AMIPartNumber = coalesce(c.Item,e.Item), a.AMIDescription = coalesce(c.Description, e.Description),a.OEMDescription = coalesce(b.OEMDescription,d.OEMDescription)FROM imports as a LEFT JOIN JD as b ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMSubNumber LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as c ON b.OEMCurrentPartNumber = c.OEMItem LEFT JOIN IH as d ON a.OEMPartNumber = d.OEMSubNumber LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as e ON d.OEMCurrentPartNumber = e.OEMItem"

'Declaring SQL Commands
        Dim sqlInsertCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSQL)
        Dim sqlSelectCommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[imports]", sqlConnection)
        Dim sqlUpdateCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(update, sqlConnection)
```

This does exactly what i need it to do.

HOWEVER, now i am trying to add another variable. For items that don't get matched in imports.AMIPartNumber i need to query another table on my other sqlserver.

Can that be done? Update the table 'imports' on one sql server with data from another table 'JD_ALL' that is on my other sql server?

I have this working to display data on site but this is for a csv file import. When displaying data on site im able to use multiple connections to fill 2 different data tables that don't have to be connected.

Comment: Set up a linked server

Comment: Im trying to setup a linked server in SQL Management Studio but i get the error "A required operation could not be completed.  You must be a member of the sysadmin role to perform this operation. (SqlManagerUI)" Im on a GoDaddy MS SQL server. Is there any way around this to get me permission? I set up the sql server in my console and even tried the Web Admin using "EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin" but keep getting permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. Either:

1) Create a new connection string to the other server in your config file and then create a new connection to it in your code. You would then execute another command to retrieve your data from this other database before you use your other connection and commands.

For example:

```
'Declaring Connection String
        Dim sqlConnectionString As String
        sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("baminterchangerConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)

       Dim sqlConnectionStringOtherDatabase As String
        sqlConnectionStringOtherDatabase = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("otherConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConnectionOtherDatabase As New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStringOtherDatabase)


Dim sqlSelectCommandToOtherDB As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OtherTable]", sqlConnectionStringOtherDatabase)

.... etc
```

2) as @Dean mentioned you can add a linked server on your sql-server instance. This does assume you have access rights to play with the configuration of SQL Server though. You can then query the other database on a different as if it's on the same server. This may save some code but requires more setup and config.